# Passing form content and POST data to service

Tags: angular

I need to pass the content of my text boxes to the `mycomponent.component.ts` file. from their I need to call a webservice to post the content.

I have 2 problems:

1. I need to know how to retrieve the form content into `mycomponent.component.ts` ?
2. I need to POST the content to a webservice.

My code so far:

```
 <div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="name" />

    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pwd">password</label>
      <input type="password" id="pwd" placeholder="Password" />
    </div>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="clickMe()">Ok</button>

  </div>
```

In the `mycomponent.component.ts`

```
ngOnInit() {
}

  ClickMe(){
     // How to retrieve the content here.
  }

}
```

Comment: start by reading these fundamental sections: https://angular.io/guide/forms or https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to first read about Angular forms. The best would be to start from official Angular tutorial:
[Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) 
That is if you already know how to bind input, but if you don't, please read about [User Input](https://angular.io/guide/user-input)
To be able to send data to server, you need to learn about [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http) When you finish with reading all of that, let me know if I can help you further.